# Different font-size to span tag inside of p

Tags: css, less

I'm having trouble with creating different font size to a span element inside p. The p is supposed to be a larger heading text and the span comes right after it with no extra spacing and the span text will be much smaller with a lighter color.

I can't get the span text to be smaller. It just stays the same size as the p text. Also there's too much space in between them and I'l like these too text lines to be very close each other.

**HTML**:

```
<p class="this-p">Hello<br><span class="this-span">Some text here</span></p>
```

**LESS**:

```
.this-p {
    font-size:1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    .this-span {
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size:0.9em !important;
        color: @gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: you seems to be missing closing p tag. which assumes the end of paragraph when a new tag is found. (_I am not sure, but I believe this_).

Comment: I just tried to make the font-size even smaller (with my original code) and realized it was working! The same font size somewhere else makes the text even smaller so I didn't realize it was working. But there's still a quite big space between these too lines of text.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem em's working relative to their parents rather than the base font size(which would be rem). Was that the issue? Also, you should note that line-height gets the base value of the em units not from it's parent but it's element. So if your body/base font size is 10 and you declare 'font-size:1.6em; line-height:1em;' the calculated line heigth will be 16px, not 10px.

Answer (score 3):

Your `LESS` works as intended, seen here: http://jsbin.com/mohur/1

> But there's still a quite big space between these too lines of text.

This is due to the lack of `line-height`. Its either inheriting from the `body` or the browser defaults. To work around this: http://jsbin.com/mohur/2

```
.this-p {
    font-size:1.6em;
    line-height: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    .this-span {
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        color: gray;
    }
}
```

Be careful with `ems` they can be tricky to deal with nested sizes.

Be careful with `line-height`. If the text goes on to two lines, you may run into issues.

I would imagine a better way of doing this would be: http://jsbin.com/mohur/3

This way you have totally control of both elements and neither inherits from the other.

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS like this

```
.this-p 
{
    font-size:1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.this-span 
{
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size:0.9em !important;
        color: gray;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/58dwt/1/)

Comment: @user3496563 See the demo.

Comment: @user3496563 Replace the mentioned css section of yours and replace it with the one given above.

Comment: There seems to be something else interfering my code because this doesn't work.

Comment: @user3496563 Sometimes you might have used the nesting pattern for other styles as well, like you used here. There is no such nesting in CSS. But nesting is there in case of media queries.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham I think OP is using LESS.

Answer (score 0):

just take out the branched span from inside the p block...

```
.this-p {
    font-size:1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.this-span {
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size:0.9em !important;
    color: @gray;
}
```

i might be wrong, but there is not branching such as this in CSS...always have the elements styled separately...except for SASS, of course...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest these css unless you are using SASS model.

Keeping them separately would help.

```
.this-p {
   font-size:1.6em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.this-span {
   font-weight: lighter;
   font-size:0.9em !important;
   color: @gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong in css. Make it as follows and also make sure to close `<p>` tag

```
.this-p {
    font-size:1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
    .this-span {
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size:0.9em !important;
        color: @gray;
    }
```

Take a look at ***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3asZC/1011/)***